# dynamic gnuplot with slot specific info display

Tags: python, dynamic, gnuplot

Can I use gnuplot to generate a plot as shown in [image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/intumyspace/6911907271/) (drawn with dia).

I am receiving 3 types of packets and need to plot their timeline. All slots begin with a beacon, any 1 of the other 2 packets may arrive in a given slot.

1. pls suggest what set of commands i need to use , if yes.
2. can I call gnuplot from the (python)program that is actually decoding the packet content, rather than writing into a file and then reading from it. Or is there a better tool to plot such dynamic content over a lot of slots in order to analyse

Answer (score 0):

1. You could make use of `boxxyerrorbars` as demonstrated [here](http://chartgnuplot.sourceforge.net/plotStyle.html) in the section `Plot styles of combination of boxes and error bars`. Although the script of the link uses perl converting it to python should not be too hard...
2. You can use [Gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) to plot data with gnuplot from within python.

Comment: import strict 
from gnuplot import * 
chart = Gnuplot.Gnuplot() 
g.hardcopy('plotStyle_10.ps', enhanced=1, color=1) 
g.title('A simple  example')g.plot([[1,5], [2,4], [3,3], [4,2],[5,1],[6,0]]) my @xerr = (0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6); 
my $boxerrorbars = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    xdata => [@x],
    ydata => [[@y], [@xerr]],
    style => 'boxerrorbars',
    title => 'boxerrorbars',); #step-2
$chart->plot2d($boxerrorbars, $boxxyerrorbars); #step-3

Comment: i could not run perl code, gives error, Couldn't find Chart/Gnuplot.pm I tried to learn a bit of perl and mapped the code to python, could you help me with step -2 and step-3. I have been trying to edit my post but it says i dont have right post images. kindly bear with code in comment, thanks

Comment: @mohdrafiq Sorry I don't have any experience with perl especially not with its gnoplot library. I am sorry that I edited your post inserting an image which made it impossible for you to edit your question ^^